# Error while finding module in VS code debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, vscode-debugger

I have tried different solutions to enable me to debug a python file in my project.
Here is my file structure:

project-main

-ns

-examples

and several Python files in examples and ns. Basically, all example files are using ns or other imported modules. I also have a conda environment that I have already activated in vs code terminal. And here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "project-main.examples",
        }
    ]
}
```

I select Start debugging from the Run menu but I keep getting this error:

```
E+00000.063: Error determining module path for sys.argv

             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 296, in run_module
                 spec = find_spec(options.target)
               File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
                 parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-main'
```

.
.
.

```
       File "c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\common\log.py", line 215, in swallow_exception
         _exception(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'project-main.examples' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-main')
```

Comment: Can you provide your folder structure? I think there's something wrong with your folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "examples.run_this",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

so basically for the module field, I have to enter the name of the subfolder that includes the main running file (run_this) and then the name of the running file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I provide a possible answer. If your module `project-main` is located under the workspace, you can try the following way.

If you didn't set `cwd`, default would be the root directory of the file. During the debugging process, the module cannot be found. You can set `cwd` in the `launch.json` file by add the following codes:

```
"cwd"："${workspaceFolder}"
```